# Azure: How to purchase more vip's for my virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

i simply would like to know how to purchase more (vips) for my virtual machine, as i need to run ssl on my sites and you can only run one ssl certificate on a live ip in iis.

if this is not possible how would i go about using multiple SSL certificates?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not a feature of Azure, but is planned in a future release, I believe. Unfortunately the only way to get multiple VIPs at the moment is to use multiple VMs or multiple cloud services.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim stated, you get one IP per cloud service (which can equate to one or more virtual machine instances behind that IP address). To run with multiple SSL certs, you can use Server Name Indication (SNI), available with IIS8+Server 2012. Server 2012 is available for both Virtual Machines and web/worker role stateless VMs.

Here's an [article](http://www.vic.ms/microsoft/windows-azure/multiples-ssl-certificates-on-windows-azure-cloud-services/) on setting up a web/worker cloud service with SNI, but you should be able to use the same technique with a Virtual Machine.